# What happens when auto number reaches its pre-set max?

Tags: auto-number

I have a standard field that I have assigned the following Display format "A-{0000}". What happens when it reaches A-9999? I'm not able to find the answer online and I want to make sure it does not restart. I need this to be a unique field.

Comment: The "possible duplicate" says "I don't know what happens when it hits 11 digits" so does not answer this question.

Comment: Fair enough - the question states the behavior of what happens when the number ticks over the digits specified in the display format, is what I was getting at. The items below don't get at going higher than 10bn records either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just created a custom object using an Auto Number Display Format of `T-{0}` and names like `T-10` and `T-11` were created.

So looks like no restarting, with the formatting expanding as you might expect for the numbers that use more characters than specified by the format.

**PS**

And there is this Salesforce Knowledge Article on the subject stolen from DerekF's comment: [Effects when auto-number field exceeds the specified digits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000338274&type=1&mode=1).

Comment: There's also an official help page that says that this is the expected behavior: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000338274&type=1

Comment: Hi @DerekF that's probably a better answer - why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: didn't find that page Derek before. Thank you both